# How to force usage of GNU assembler directives in a MASM format assembly file, and vice versa

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, masm, gnu-assembler

I have a MASM-format assembly file that is part of a C library. I want to have this file also assemble on *nix, which we assume will have gcc installed, and hence use the GNU assembler.

The problem I am running into is assembler directives; I wonder if there is a way to have both assemblers understand the same directives, or at least select from some options. There was some hope here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

... but it was dashed when I realized it's for inline ASM.

When looking at Agner Fog's manuals, there was reference made to his 'objconv' tool, which I can use to take my object file, and then disassemble it into the form that I want. This is obviously less clean than what I had in mind.

I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks, 
-mw

example that works in MASM, but I need the **GNUC** part to contain 'reg1 = rdi', etc. when passed through 'as':

```
IFDEF _MSC_VER
    reg1 textequ <rcx>
    reg2 textequ <rdx>
    reg3 textequ <r8>
ELSEIFDEF __GNUC__
    reg1 textequ <rdi>
    reg2 textequ <rsi>
    reg3 textequ <rdx>
ELSE
    ;error
ENDIF
```

Comment: Is your problem the assembler directives (as you say)?  Or the intel vs att opcode dialects?  If it's the dialect, take a look at https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html#i386_002dVariations

Comment: It is the former; we know that ".intel_syntax selects Intel mode" and why it is necessary. The problem that arises is assembler directives not being covered by a similar syntax switch.

Comment: Sorry for doubting you.  Sometimes I skip over the easy stuff, usually to my regret.  I don't know what else I can suggest without seeing some specifics (and maybe not even then).  Something else to consider: 'as' is available on Windows.  If you have to select one format, well...

Comment: As an example: the function calling convention for code compiled on 64-bit Windows requires certain registers be used for passing up to 4 arguments, the rest are on the stack http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf, table 4.1. The same table shows registers that need to be saved & restored. I want to use preprocessor directives to: check which assembler I'm with via ifdef, and define some text equates to alias the necessary registers (these directives also differs between assemblers). If that is doable, the other obvious thing one needs to do with functions should follow.

Comment: Well, I've got a thought.  How ugly it is depends on how desperate you are.  Ask yourself these two questions: 1) If you could run this asm file thru the regular c preprocessor instead of the lame, dialect-specific asm one, could you do what you wanted?  2) Why can't you do that?  For example, in VS, add a file foo.preasm with your current asm content, give it a custom build type, make the command line: cl %(FullPath) -EP > %(Filename).asm and set Outputs: foo.asm. You can add /D entries to this command as required.  A similar approach should work for *ix.

Comment: You are an absolute beast. This works perfectly. Now I just have to figure out how to make VS take the output valid ASM into the rest of compilation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from David Wohlferd above works. I'm just framing it in the context which solved my problem.

To make Visual Studio pre-process this file which contains C preprocessor directives and valid assembly in Intel syntax (which is converted to AT&T syntax with a switch), make a pre-build event. Put "cl /EP topsecret.preasm > topsecret.asm" in that event for your project.

Then, for each file (which you should include in your project sources) make a custom build event (right click file, go to properties, make it an item of type 'custom build tool'). Then make the command line contain the assembler command line that you want. For example,

"ml64.exe /c -D "MS_COMPILER" /Fo"topsecret.obj" "Path\to\topsecret.asm"